# Boolean Result from a string

Tags: ms-access, vba, boolean-expression

I am using MS Access and would like to store items for review in a table for example:

[image]

I will gather the details from that table using the following details (in an open recordset):

```
Field_Review = rst1![Field_NM] & ""
Evaluation = rst1![Eval_TP] & ""
Goal = rst1![Field_Val] & ""
```

I will use the following code to pull the values from the open form:

```
strResult = Forms![Main].Form(Field_Review).Value
```

I would like to return a boolean result using something like this:

```
blnResult = Goal & Evaluation & strResult
```

I set `blnResult`: `Dim blnResult as Boolean`.
I keep getting an error "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch."

When I try and debug I notice I am not returning the desired boolean; however, a string with the literal value "APPROVED=APPROVED".

Any hints to make the evaluation result in a normal boolean would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Eval()` may get you what you want.  Here's an Immediate window example.

Your values ...

```
Goal = "APPROVED"
Evaluation = "="
strResult = "APPROVED"
```

When you concatenate those, include quotes to delimit the text values within the string.  If you want to use double quotes, put 2 wherever you want one to appear in the final string.  However single quotes are easier for me ...

```
strExpression = "'" & Goal & "'" & Evaluation & "'" & strResult & "'"
? strExpression
'APPROVED'='APPROVED'
```

And now evaluate that expression and store it in your variable.  You don't actually need `CBool()` ... just `Eval(strExpression)` should be enough ... but I included it here because then `blnResult` will display as True instead of -1.  Both are the same number, but I wanted to avoid confusion over display format.

```
blnResult = CBool(Eval(strExpression))
? blnResult
True
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfect. I appreciate the detail about CBool() that you included, that helped prevent an additional question.

Comment: Great.  You're welcome.  Just as FYI, we don't revise the question title to indicate answered --- the checkmarked answer (thanks for that) serves that purpose.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.